# Cache like stackoverflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm creating a ASP.NET MVC 2 application that envolve a section like questions here in stackoverflow (mine is with exams is another kind of application but can be extrapolate to same general idea of SO).

OK I'm creating a cache per page, its mean something like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=60, VaryByParam="page")]
ActionResult AllQuestions(int page){...}
```

But i want to invalidate that cache when a new question is created. What can i do.

I'm open to suggestions, perhaps this is not the best way to solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your questions are stored in a SQL database you could [setup an SQL expiration policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3w8402y(VS.80).aspx) so that when data changes the cache will expire.

Comment: @UpTheCreek, yes SQL Server only.

Answer (score 0):

Darin is correct.  Additionally, if you don't have SQL Server, or don't want to use it as the cache dependency, you can create a custom cache dependency, as 15seconds has a tutorial on:  http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040518.htm

Answer (score 0):

Remember, [there are only two hard problems in computer science](http://www.davidslog.com/14478836/there-are-only-two-hard-problems-in-computer), and cache invalidation is one them. Don't add the trouble of caching until you need it. As always, avoid premature optimization like this.